# Suspend in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a project in JavaScript using NodeJS. I see this code in there from my coworker that says:
`this.suspend();`
I'm told that it's native JavaScript, however I've looked on this site along with many others and can't find anything about a suspend function. Does anyone know anything about it or where I can get more info about it? Thanks!

Comment: What is 'this' in this context?

Answer (score 0):

I could find 3 different native suspend() methods in MDN:

- webRequest.StreamFilter.suspend() [reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/StreamFilter/suspend ]
- AudioContext.suspend() [reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/suspend ]
- OfflineAudioContext.suspend() [reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext/suspend ]